# Android NDK OS dependent library

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

I am using Qcom OMX decoder sample for a project. So I have to use different libraries (.so) for different OS version. these libraries are precompiled for each OS version. and I load them inside Android.mk:

Android.MK

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := qcomomxintermediate_lp  //I want to change this depending on the OS version
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/libqcomomxsample_lp.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=  qcomomxintermediate_lp
```

This works fine. But how do I load different libraries depending on the OS the app is running on? This library is used to build my NDK project.

Currently I have to manually edit the Android.mk file if I want to run the app on 5.0.1 or 5.1.1

Thanks